# Hotel California: Former moderator stuck in room

Tags: bug, chat, moderators

We recently had [an election](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1) in which two of our former pro-tem mods, who both did an excellent job, stepped down.

Kind of.

Despite giving back his diamond on the site, and not having access to our per-site moderator room anymore, Gilles' avatar is still there:

[image: poor guy can't get out]

Based on this, it might be a good idea to refresh a user's presence when their access to the room changes.

Comment: Interesting that only one of the two is "stuck"... Did the other mod never utilize the room?

Comment: @Catija I suspect that due to time zones, the other moderator wasn't in the room when his diamond was removed. I've seen this before when another moderator on another site stepped down, so I think it's fairly reproducible.

Comment: _"You can checkout any time you like, but you can never leave."_

Comment: if it was any other chat room, fine, but this one ... he has to stay stuck